# Laravel 5.2,set validation for POST method, not for GET

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I am learning Laravel 5.2. I am trying to do a form validation example.Have read the doc for validation and my code using create and store methods using the validation request class is working. Now I am trying to do both `POST` and `GET` in the same method. I have created my `request` class,and my rules method is defined as this

```
public function rules()
    {   
        if($this->method() == 'POST'){
            return [
                'first_name' => 'required'
            ];

        }else{
            return [];
        }
    }
```

My controller  method is declared as

```
public function create(myRequest $request){
 //save and display the data
}
```

but when I load my method,I get a blank page saying,`forbidden`. I tried returning `null` value for GET, but its not working.

```
    Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() 
must be of the type array, null given
```

Isn't possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you see in your myRequest validation file, you will find this method.

```
public function authorize()
{
    return false;
}
```

which is for, allow only those user who are authentic to this section/post/comment etc. So change this to

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

and one thing more for your information, This is not the correct way to pass validation Request object with `GET` method, its always passing with POST/PUT/Delete methods